# Why return a clone of an object in oop?

Tags: php, oop, clone, slim

I recently had to use [`Slim\Http\Message`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Http/blob/master/src/Message.php) and [`Slim\Http\Request`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Http/blob/master/src/Request.php) to get the users posted data.

I noticed something in the method [`withBody()`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Http/blob/master/src/Message.php#L296) where it was returning a clone of the object instead of `$this`.

This caused me some trouble as I couldn't get my application to work until I assigned `$request->withBody(...)` to a variable (`$request`) and then carried on using that new variable in my script.

I have a mock example to explain (see comments in the code);

```
class Request {
    protected $body;

    public function addBody($body) {
        $clone = clone $this;
        $clone->body = $body;
        return $clone;
    }

    public function getBody() {
        return $this->body;
    }
}

$request = new Request;

// this will return NULL
$request->addBody([
    'name' => 'john',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
]);

var_dump($request->getBody());

// -----------------------

// but this will return the "body" that was passed in above.
$request = $request->addBody([
    'name' => 'john',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
]);

var_dump($request->getBody());
```

I see what is happening here. But I don't understand *why* a class would be implemented like this.

What are the benefits? Why restrict a developer in this way?

Comment: You may want to research "[Immutable Objects](https://blog.joefallon.net/2015/08/immutable-objects-in-php/)".

Comment: And functional programming

Comment: Voted to close as opinion based. Try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com I cannot vote to migrate it there

Comment: It's not opinion based, he wants to understand the Design Pattern of immutable Value Objects

Answer (score 2):

Slim uses the PSR-7 HTTP Messaging Interface standard, which describes itself as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Psr\Http\Message;

/**
 * HTTP messages consist of requests from a client to a server and responses
 * from a server to a client. This interface defines the methods common to
 * each.
 *
 * Messages are considered immutable; all methods that might change state MUST
 * be implemented such that they retain the internal state of the current
 * message and return an instance that contains the changed state.
 *
 * @see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7230.txt
 * @see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7231.txt
 */
interface MessageInterface
{
    //etc
}
```

"Messages are considered immutable". They are considered Value objects, which must never change state, and if you do want to change state, a new instance is returned.

Here's a link explaining Value Objects http://deviq.com/value-object/

And a little extract from the page I linked:

> A Value Object is an immutable type that is distinguishable only by
>   the state of its properties. That is, unlike an Entity, which has a
>   unique identifier and remains distinct even if its properties are
>   otherwise identical, two Value Objects with the exact same properties
>   can be considered equal. Value Objects are a pattern first described
>   in Evans’ Domain-Driven Design book, and further explained in Smith
>   and Lerman’s Domain-Driven Design Fundamentals course.

Hopefully this will help you understand why!

Finally, have a wee look at the actual PSR-7 Standard here http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/

Comment: The question was WHAT are benefits and WHY it restricts the usage to be so complicated. You are answering nothing of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask the same question...

The only benefit I can discover in this design is that you can chain some method calls together like in [PSR-7 HttpClients](https://www.dotkernel.com/dotkernel3/what-is-psr-7-and-how-to-use-it/) this..

```
$request = $request
  ->withBody($body)
  ->withHeader('Content-Lenght', strlen($body))
  ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  ->withHeader('User-Agent', 'xxxx');
```

But in my opinion that small benefit is not worth to accept all negative effects of this.
E.g. with this Design for each method call a copy of the opject is created.
What means a lot of memory wasting when you have big data objects, or when you have many method calls.